# 50 wt% of something // ~~ plurality

Tags: grammar

I have two questions.

1. Is it allowed to write " 30 wt% a polyamine" instead of "30 wt% of a ployamine" in patent context and grammatically?

   2. I know "a plurality of As" means "a number of As."
      Can you say " a A plurality " to mean "a plurality of As"?

Please give me answers in consideration of patent context. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. I might just write 30 wt% polyamine.
2. No, that construction is not used with "plurality."

Comment: Agreed to both 1 and 2.